# Why can't I set mail account as default (Outlook 2010)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I have 3 mail accounts defined in Outlook 2010 (Windows 10). Two are different mailboxes on the same server. The third is with another provider. All are IMAP. I would like to designate one of these accounts as my default mail account, but that option is disabled for all but one of my accounts. Why is the "Set As Default" option not available for all of my accounts?

Comment: Have you checked the default data file? Whether it's set to the correct one, which should be the current default account?

Comment: The only data file I can designate as default is "Outlook", which is not an email account that I use. Is it not possible to designate one of my main (IMAP) accounts as default because there is no data file associated with them?

Comment: What does "there is no data file associated with them" refer to? If there is no data file, where are your messages, calendars, contacts, etc. stored? It could be the cause, have you tried re-adding the account to your profile?